# Powershell: Run a BAT from another BAT and Supply Variables

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, scripting

Super short version: I've got a massive BAT file that I'm looking to make into a smaller series of child-BAT files I can run from a single parent-BAT file while supplying variables.

Confused?

Example: One thing the main BAT file I have now does is it sweeps a number of different locations for debris files and folders, and deletes them. It's identical verbiage for each sweep, the only thing that changes is the folder.

So what I'd like to do is construct a BAT file that does something like this:

```
Run Clear_Debris.bat
$searchdrive = "H:\"

Run Clear_Debris.bat
$searchdrive = "W:\"

Run Drive_Migration.bat
$sourcedrive = "H:\"
$destdrive = "W:\"
```

And so on. Basically, a single BAT can invoke other BATs (which don't have values specified for variables), and specify what those BATs should use as values for their variables. That way I can break out all the individual functions into their own BAT files that I can run individually when I need to, or else when I need to make a change to one of the routines, I only have to do it in one place instead of more than one.

Is this possible?

Comment: This seems really convoluted. Why this use case, vs just doing this in PS natively? Honestly either use .bat/.cmd or .ps1.  The way you have the variables specified would only work in PS. You can natively use .bat/.cmd and use the variable methods there directly. See these resources: ['batch file variables'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27batch+file+variables%27&t=h_&ia=web) If you are doing this in a corporate environment, then just use [Windows Server FSRM for file/folder management](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27windows+fsrm%27+%27file+and+folder+management%27&t=h_&ia=web). What's in the bat?

Comment: I just gave a small sample of what the BAT file actually has. This is a full fundown:
* Copy files from one drive to another (4 times)
* Clear folders of debris (4 times)
* Search directory for folders with specific names and move to deep storage (4 times)
* Mirror destination folder back to source (4 times)

So there's a lot happening in a single BAT file, with a lot of steps repeated, and I want to make things simpler on myself by running the same batches repeatedly with different variables.

Comment: Note that PowerShell is incidental to your task, given that you want to create _batch files_. (Your sample code uses PowerShell syntax to create variables, which wouldn't work in a batch file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Place all your `.bat` (`.cmd`) files in the same folder.
- Call each subordinate batch file using the `call` command, to ensure that execution continues in the main batch file.
- Use path prefix `%~dp0` to ensure that the subordinate batch files can be located alongside the main batch file, irrespective of what the working directory is (`%~dp0` expands to the full path of the directory in which the executing batch file is located, *always followed by a* `\` - run `for /?` for details)

  - If, instead, you want to place the subordinate batch files in a *subfolder* of the main batch file instead, say `util`, simply append that subfolder's name, say `%~dp0util\`.
- The subordinate batch files automatically see the main batch file's variables, though you can localize variable changes performed in the subordinate batch files with `setlocal`

  - However, for conceptual clarity and maintainability, consider designing your subordinate batch files to accept *arguments* to be passed by the main batch file on invocation, accessible in the callee as `%1`, `%2`, ...

Outline of the main batch file:

```bash
@echo off & setlocal

:: Run Clear_Debris.bat
set "searchdrive=H:\"
call "%dp0Clear_Debris.bat"

:: Run Clear_Debris.bat with a different %searchdrive% value.
set "searchdrive=W:\"
call "%~dp0Clear_Debris.bat"

:: ...
```

You may also want to act on the `%ERRORLEVEL%` value after each `call` to check if a subordinate batch file reported an error.

Comment: Hate to say it but it's not working as intended. The main BAT file does come up, but it's not forwarding the value I set to the second BAT file.

Comment: This is my syntax: "@echo off & setlocal

set "$sourceDir=K:\Work Stuff VI"
call "Subroutines\Clear_Debris.bat"

Comment: The problem being that when Clear_Debris.bat runs, the variable $sourceDir doesn't have a value (it's formatted as a Powershell command if that makes a difference).

Comment: It might also be worth noting that the Clear_Debris.bat file invokes Powershell tools to do its work; that's why I said it was formatted for PowerShell to start with. This is one of the commands: "Get-ChildItem -recurse -path $sourceDir -filter $searchfolder | remove-item -force -recurse -verbose"

So what I'm trying to do is define $sourceDir in the super-BAT file and then have it run Clear_Debris.bat with that value for $sourceDir.

Comment: Figured it out: had to add "$sourceDir=$Env:sourceDir" to Clear_Debris.bat

Comment: Glad you figured it out, @tnpir4002, but note that you can use direct _string interpolation on the `cmd.exe` side_, by referring to environment variable `sourcedire` (which you must declare with `set` and without `$`, as shown in the answer) as `%sourcedir%` in your PowerShell command, specifically as: ``\"%sourcedir%\"``. Your indirect technique is generally only needed with variable values that would cause escaping headaches.

Comment: So how do I actually implement that? At the start of my Powershell commands (in the individual BAT files) I have this now: "$sourceDir=$Env:sourceDir"

Do I just replace that with " \"%sourcedir%\" "?

Comment: @tnpir4002, you use `set` to define your variable: `set "sourceDir=c:\path\to\dir"`, and, in the `powershell.exe` / `pwsh.exe` call, you refer to it as ``\"%sourcedir%\"`` - no PowerShell syntax needed.

Comment: Like this? call "Subroutines\Draft_Materials.bat" \"%sourcedir%\"

Comment: @tnpir4002, no - you needn't pass _arguments_ to your helper batch files (though you may choose to change your approach to that, but that requires more extensive changes): your helper batch files will  automatically see the variables defined in the main batch file. The ``\"%sourcedir%\"`` is only needed _as part of the call to PowerShell CLI_ (`powershell.exe` or `pwsh.exe`). Here's a minimal example: `set "foo=c:\windows"`, then `powershell.exe -noprofile -c " Get-ChildItem \"%foo%\" "`